# Is Sunbeam's beam considered sunlight, for the purposes of Sunlight Hypersensitivity?

Tags: spells, dnd-5e, undead

Compare Sunbeam's opening line:

> "A beam of brilliant **light** flashes out from your hand in a
>   5-foot-wide, 60-foot-line."

to Sunburst's opening line:

> "Brilliant **sunlight** flashes in a 60-foot radius centered on a
>   point you choose within range."

This seems to suggest that, for the purposes of Sunlight Hypersensitivity (e.g., that of Vampires), Sunbeam and Sunburst are different. However, Sunbeam has a second component:

> "For the duration, a mote of brilliant radiance shines in your hand.
>   It sheds bright light in a 30-foot radius and dim light for an
>   additional 30 feet. The light is **sunlight.**"

Does the sunlight "property" apply only to the mote, or to the beam attack as well? RAW, it would seem like the former (based on the quotes above; the name of the spell suggests otherwise), but it's counterintuitive that the least powerful component of a spell (non-damage dealing, presumably 'utility-oriented') has a damage-dealing property that the more powerful, damage-dealing one doesn't.

One other wrinkle:

RAW, it would seem that Sunburst doesn't trigger SHS, despite the fact that it's a L8 spell that explicitly creates sunlight. Is it reasonable to house-rule that the affected vampire(s) takes the 20 damage, at the time of casting (even if they succeed the saving throw, since the entire burst is still sunlight)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As is noted in your answer, the mechanics here are pretty clear:

- The vampire takes normal damage from Sunbeam (6d8, with the option to repeat on subsequent turns) and Sunburst (12d6).
- In the case of Sunbeam, the vampire takes an additional 20 damage at the start of its turn, if within the 60-foot radius.

The vampire doesn't take extra damage from Sunburst, because there is no sunlight at the start of its turn. Simple enough.

Which is "better" depends on the situation. 12d6 will generally do quite a lot more damage than 6d8, but 20 damage / round narrows the gap almost immediately.

This does mean that in this particular instance, the level six spell may be a bit better suited to the situation than the level eight spell. Never fear, the eighth level spell will *usually* be a lot better (hits more targets for more damage, does other useful things).

## Mechanics vs. Flavor

The mechanics above are pretty clear. But the mechanics may not fit the lore you have in your head about vampires (I think this is what SSD is getting at with his comment). As the DM, you have two options here.

1. **Fit the lore to the mechanics**

   The first is to fit the lore to the mechanics. Here, it's pretty simple... Vampires burn in the sunlight, but it takes a little sizzling before they start to hurt. Sunburst just doesn't shine the light on them long enough to cause problems (other than, you know, the massive amount of radiant damage and potential blindness).

   A longer dose of sunlight gradually sets them on fire, triggering their weakness.
2. **Bend the mechanics to fit (your version) of the lore**

   Sunlight hurts vampires, right? So go ahead and throw an extra 20 damage onto Sunburst. It's not *the rules*, but if it makes the fight more fun, then that can be fine.

Which you choose will depend on your group, and how often you bend things in their favor ("hey, 20 extra damage!"), vs. how often you bend things against them.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, I think I have it: Sunlight Hypersensitivity (SHS) only triggers when Vampires *start* their turn in sunlight. Which means that, RAW, SHS only responds to **environmental conditions** (i.e., is there sunlight shining on the Vampire's square?). So, neither the beam itself nor Sunburst's burst seem to trigger SHS--only the Vampire starting its turn in the area of light created by the mote.

In that case, it seems that a L6 spell is patently superior to the L8 spell at slaying vampires (which are pretty deadly): every turn, for 1 minute, you can force a Con save or be blinded + 6d8 damage, +20 damage if within 30 (60?) feet. All for the price of 1 juicy L6 slot.

(Yes, Sunburst has a huge area, the blindness lasts longer, and it's 50% more damage... but you can only Sunburst 2/day at most, using your highest spell slots. It can be harder to aim, and no SHS, it would seem).

Answer (score -1):

We've always played that only the mote was sunlight. This isn't as much of a problem as the vampire is not going to willingly start it's turn in the beam anyway. Even if the beam *were* sunlight, you wouldn't get the bonus 20 pts unless the SHS creature was restrained.

Additional benefit of the sunbeam spell is that there are two area effects involved and the one with sunlight that triggers SHS *moves with you* . The Dawn spell's sunlight affect can also be moved. If you get pushback from your players, its pretty easy to point out that they wouldn't gain much from it being sunlight anyway as the SHS creature is going to be harder to restrain in the beam than just keeping the caster close to the vamp when it starts it's turn.

The beam can be left in place to act as a barrier of radiant damage and the sunlight can be carried with you as you chase a vampire (or other SHS creature ).
Furthermore the sunlight from the mote *doesn't harm your party* . People seem to imagine all the damage they can do with area effects spells not remembering that often you have to do that damage to at least 1 member of your party too.